# Display image depending on date

Tags: html, css, vbscript, benchmarking

Can anyone help with this timing code. I am trying to have an image turn on on a certain date and time and turn off on a certain date and time. This code only allows for date at 12:01. And, if I place my page on server on the 30th and want new image to turn on on the 3rd, it wouldn't work because it's not >=. I am still learning html and css so I am not very savvy at this. My web guy has given me this code but doesn't know much else about it. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
<%    
Dim today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd")
Dim startdate =  28
Dim sdate=Request("date")

''Response.Write(trackid & "<br>")
if sdate <> "" then
    startdate = sdate 
else 
    startdate = 28
end if
%>
```

Comment: What language is that? It's not JavaScript.

Comment: That doesn't look like javascript to me

Comment: While the code looks like VBScript, the `<% %>` aren't. Is this ASP code? Also, it's unclear to me what exactly you want to achieve. Showing a different image after a particular timestamp is easy. You just need to generate the `<img>` tag depending on the date. However, that will only affect new requests. If you want the client to change the image even if the user didn't refresh the page, you're going to need client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using javascript to activate content in this manner. If somebody comes to your site with JS disabled your desired functionality will break.
You also aren't using Javascript. Is that Python?

You should use server-side functinality to automatically publish your content, or do it manually at the desired time.

Also it looks like your start date is day-oriented only. You should be using a timestamp because otherwise it could be trying to put your content live every month on the 28th based off what I'm seeing here.

I'd suggest going back and approaching this in a safer way.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like visual basic to me. I'm not going to say definitely not something you should be using for the web. (although that was my first instinct)  But certainly not a first choice.

How is your start date represented in that code? "28" seems odd. We can only assume what that stands for (like dude wad did, 28th of every month? I would have assumed 28th day of the year eg. Janurary 28th)

It's unclear from *just* your code what DateTime.Now and Request("date") are and how they differ.  I know stack overflow had that popup saying don't ask for clarification in an answer, But then It's kind of backwards to say that (for new users) but not allow new users to post comments to ask... (50 reputation points? really?)

It also seems like the problems you are describing is not related to the code you provided. You asked us about questions on your code but provided the code given to you by your "web guy" which you don't understand?

I suggest getting your "web guy" to comment his code/provide explanations.  Either that, or Show us YOUR code so we can examine what might be wrong.  I don't see any ">=" comparison anywhere in the code you provided.

**Sorry for the tangent, but to answer your question in general:**

I *do* think I have somewhat of a grasp of what you're trying to do, and (I think dudewad) was correct in his assumption that you're restarting the count every month.

You should have a continuous count of the entire year, either that or get a server time. (How is your server setup?)  Usually there is a time function or something similar you can use instead of trying to count time yourself. Usually this takes into account months, days AND years and is suitable for most situations.

so you won't have the problem of your date count "resetting" when you pass a certain number. (i'm guessing 30 or 31)

Edit: Actually I see that you are using a time function now.

(sorry, it's been a while since I used visual basic, and I think this is a modified version since it's more object oriented than VB used to be ==maybe it's .NET? I've barely worked with that but I DO know the code looks more similar to c languages without the curly brackets)

but you're only parsing the "day" portion of the date. Parse the entire date. Year, Month, and Day, and code your "dailies" for each unique day.

Finally from your initial question, it seems that you think this is CSS or HTML. It isn't, you're venturing into full fledged programming/coding.  python and php are the most common server-side languages used to generate dynamic webpages.  I think you should check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/  The VB code that you recieved should make more sense. (I didn't link you to a VB tutorial because php is more relavent to web development, and that tutorial won't have much irrelavent information a VB tutorial would likely have)  The concepts of coding are transferable through many languages. Find out how your server is set up. Then come back if you have more troubles. We'll be happy to help.